# Login token with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

I'm in the process of wiring up Log In functionality with React and am running into issues with user session tokens.

**Problem:**
I'm able to successfully login and create a user session token (verified via console), however, once I refresh the page after successful login, it redirects me back to the log in page as if I do not have a token.

Why is this token issue appearing? Is it even a token issue?

I've coded react so that if !token, then direct to Log In form, and if there is a token, then redirect to placeholder ('account')

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Container, Button, Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { getFromStorage, setInStorage } from '../utils/storage'

export default class LoginUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      token: '',
      logInError: '',
      logInEmail: '',
      logInPassword: '',
    }

    this.onChangeLogInEmail = this.onChangeLogInEmail.bind(this);
    this.onChangeLogInPassword = this.onChangeLogInPassword.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const obj = getFromStorage('OI_Login')
    if (obj && obj.token) {
      const { token } = obj
      // verify token
      fetch('http://localhost:5001/users/verify?token' + token)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.success) {
            this.setState({
              token,
              isLoading: false
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false
            })
          }
        })

    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      })

    }
  }

  // ON CHANGE
  onChangeLogInEmail(e) {
    this.setState({
      logInEmail: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onChangeLogInPassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      logInPassword: e.target.value
    })
  }

  logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    })
    const obj = getFromStorage('OI_Login')
    if (obj && obj.token) {
      const { token } = obj
      // verify token
      fetch('http://localhost:5001/users/logout?token' + token)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.success) {
            this.setState({
              token: '',
              isLoading: false,
              logInError: ''
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false
            })
          }
        })

    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      })
    }
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {
      logInEmail,
      logInPassword
    } = this.state

    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    })

    //post request to backend
    fetch('http://localhost:5001/users/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: logInEmail,
        password: logInPassword
      }),
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (json.success) {
          setInStorage('OI_Login', { token: json.token })
          this.setState({
            logInError: json.message,
            isLoading: false,
            logInEmail: '',
            logInPassword: '',
            token: json.token
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            logInError: json.message,
            isLoading: false
          })
        }
      })

  }

  render() {
    const {
      isLoading,
      token,
      logInError,
      logInEmail,
      logInPassword,
    } = this.state

    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="justify-content-center">
            <Spinner animation="border" />
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }

    if (!token) {
      return (
        <>
          <Container>
            <h3>Log In</h3>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  required
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  value={logInEmail}
                  onChange={this.onChangeLogInEmail}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  required
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  value={logInPassword}
                  onChange={this.onChangeLogInPassword}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <div>
                {
                  (logInError) ? (
                    <p>{logInError}</p>
                  ) : (null)
                }
              </div>
              <Form.Group>
                <Button variant="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onSubmit} type="submit">Log In</Button>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
            <a href='/register'>Register</a>
          </Container>
        </>
      )
    }

      return (
        <>
          <p>Account</p>
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.logout}>Log Out</Button>
        </>
      )

  }

}
```

**Token storage**

```
export function getFromStorage(key) {
  if (!key) {
    return null
  }

  try {
    const valueStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
    if (valueStr) {
      return JSON.parse(valueStr)
    }
    return null
  } catch (err) {
    return null
  }
}

export function setInStorage(key, obj) {
  if (!key) {
    console.error('Error: Key is missing')
  }

  try {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

}
```

Comment: please show storage code also

Comment: how are you storing token?

Comment: @niks Added token storage to question

Comment: @Udit added token storage to question

Comment: @revup88 HI, The problem with this is componentDidMount runs and doesn't wait for the getFromStorage function to complete. If you can try making componentDidMount Asynchronous and await for getFromStorage, try this and let me know.

example :
`async componentDidMount(){
    const obj = await getFromStorage('OI_Login')
   /// your rest of the code
} `

Comment: @Udit Thank you for the suggestion. I gave that a try and the same result occurred. Successful login + token > 'Account' > [Hit refresh] > redirected back to the log in page.

When the login + token is successful, then the /login routing should only show 'Account' on refresh, not the log in page

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the token to the cookie when you got it.
And get the token from the cookie after page refreshing.